# Publish Office 365 add in on Office Store

Tags: development, office, azure, office-365-developer

Is necessity to deploy a office 365 add in on azure web app before publish to office store?

I am using visual studio 2015 to develop outllook add in for office 365.
But i am confused there why i should deploy my solution to azure web app?
Is it necessary or there are any other way to publish add in to office store with out host externally ?

Comment: If you want to publish to office store, that means your will be publicly available for everyone. In that case of course the app should be published on some externally available service. But Azure is not requirement, it can be any hosting.

Comment: @Kai Thanks . So as per your comment i understood that it must be published at any web app and then pass that web app URL to <manifest>.xml . Right?

Comment: Right, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks @Kai Is there any alternative way to publish add ins or apps to office  store with out deployed on external resource ? IF yes then can you give me steps which needs to be perform.

Comment: Personally I'm not familiar if it's possible. If you want to distribute the app to your organization only, you can use corporate catalog or exchange (for outlook apps).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51429/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-kai).